# jQuery validation separate elements share one validation test

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I'm working on a simple billing info form to collect credit card information.

I have two Select inputs:

```
<select class="form-control exp_month exp" id="expiration_month" name="expiration_month">
<select class="form-control exp_year exp" id="expiration_year" name="expiration_year">
```

I am trying to have separate 'required' errors for the fields (i.e "select month", "select year"), however, I also need to have a shared error when the date is older than today, so if either month or year are updated and it's an older date the user will see only one "select a future date" message.

I played around with validator.addMethod("exp"), and the validator errorPlacement but it seems like every fix I make breaks something else.

EDIT:

```
jQuery.validator.addMethod("exp", function (value, element) {

    if ($('.exp_year').val() != "" && $('.exp_month').val() != "" && new Date($('.exp_year').val(), $('.exp_month').val()) < Date.now()) {
        $.validator.messages.exp = "Please select a future expiration date.";
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}, "Please select something.");


var validator = $("#new-card-form").first().validate({
    rules: {
        expiration_month: 'required',
        expiration_year: 'required'
    },
    groups: {
        //ExpirationDate: "expiration_month expiration_year"
    },
    messages: {
        expiration_month: 'Please select a month.',
        expiration_year: 'Please select a year.'
    },
    errorPlacement: function (error, element) {
        if (element.hasClass("exp")) {
            if ($(".exp_past").length == 0) {
                error.insertAfter(".exp_month");
                error.addClass("exp_past");
            }
            $(".exp").valid(); // used to remove error class from both dates

        }
        else
            error.insertAfter(element);
    }
});
```

Comment: You don't need to use `.first()` when your selector is targeting an `id`.  Since `id` is unique to the page, it's always going to be first.

Answer (score 0):

You can have an error message on each field with an option to [group messages from certain fields together](http://jqueryvalidation.org/validate/#groups).

AFAIK, there is no way to *conditionally* group messages together.  There is also no provided method for *dynamically* toggling the options for `.validate()`.

A possible fix would be to use a single field for entering the expiration date.  You could use a custom method to ensure this single field is in the proper format.

---

**BTW**:

```
$("#new-card-form").first().validate({ ...
```

The usage of `.first()` is completely superfluous when your selector is targeting an `id`.  Since any `id` is always unique to the page, it's going to be the first, the last, and the only one.  If you've used the same `id` more than once, then your HTML is invalid and the page will be likely broken.